# chart.js not getting rendered inside ng-template in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

### description

i have declared chart.js inside `ng-template` but chart is not rendering properly

### sample code

```
<div style="display: block; width: 100%">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="qualitySurveyTemp"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #qualitySurveyTemp>
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</ng-template>
```

it is working fine when i use like below

```
<div style="display: block; width: 100%">
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-barchart-sjamlr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that because you are using trying to plot the chart in a sub template it is not available known in the `ngOnInit` hook. You can see this by trying to log `document.getElementById('canvas')`, this will return null. If you change to the `ngAfterViewInit` hook to create the chart it works fine:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-barchart-uqqnay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your template and wrap your canvas-element inside a div. Don't know the cause to it but the problem seems to appear when the canvas-element is at the root of the template html.